# Exaplin a limit example in graph

Tags: limits, graphing-functions

Let $f(x) = x $ for $x \ge 0$ then $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 1.$

Now, how could I exaplin it on a graph? I can't uderstand from the graph why the limit approaches $1$. It seems to me that when $x$ get closer and closer to $0$ it approaches $0$.

Edit:

The entire function is $f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x^2\textrm{ for $x \le 0$} \\
      x \textrm{ for $x \ge 0$} \\
   \end{cases}$

And I need to prove $f'(x)$ for $x = 0$

Then I've got $\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = \begin{cases}
 \frac{h}{h} = 1 \textrm{ for $h > 0$} \\
  h \textrm{ for $h<0$} \\
\end{cases}$

Then : $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = 0.$

Comment: This is not correct. $x$ is a continuous function and the limit is $0$ no matter how you approach it.

Comment: Are you sure the question does not ask for $\lim f'(x)$?

Comment: @almagest You're right.In the book author was talking about $f'(x)$. I got it wrong!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a kind of impossible!!! When you have $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = 1.$, it means that for every $\eta>0$ there is a $\sigma>0$  such that $|x-0^+|<\sigma$, then $|f(x)-1|<\eta$. While in your case, we have $|f(x)-1|=|x-1|$ for $x\geq 0$, and so $|f(x)-1|=|x-1|\geq 1-\sigma$. So, I think there is no such a function.